# Django Deployment on CPanel Error "Apache doesn't have read permissions to that file. Please fix the relevant file permissions."

Tags: django, apache, deployment, cpanel

I am trying to deploy a django application on cpanel. I cloned my github repository and all dependencies have been installed and everything is complete but when I try to open the website it gives me this page... What do I need to do in order to fix this? I don't have any knowledge about these file permissions and am just looking to host a small project.

[image: Error page]

Answer (score -1):

I came across the same issue and managed to fix it by changing the parent directories permission. In my case, it was `Repositories > MyProjectName`. Also, make sure you adjust the permission settings to the `passenger_wsgi.py` file.

Best of luck, and hope this helps.